# How do I not exclude charset in Content-Type when using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am attempting to use HttpClient in a .net core project to make a GET request to a REST service that accepts/returns JSON. I don't control the external service.

No matter how I try, I can't figure out to set the Content-Type header to application/json *only*.

When I use

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

it sends in the HTTP GET request:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

However, this particular service does not work with this. It will only work if the header is:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I've tried setting headers without validation, and all the approaches I've found on the web/SO doesn't apply to .net core. All the other the approaches to sending HTTP requests aren't available in .net core, so I need to figure this out. How can I exclude the charset in content-type?

EDIT with workaround

As mentioned in the answers, the service should be using the Accept header. The workaround (as Shaun Luttin has in his answer) is to add an empty content to the GET (what? GETs don't have content! yeah...). It's not pretty, but it does work.

Comment: can you  change the service?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're setting the `Accept` header. You need to set the `ContentType` header instead, which is only canonical for a POST.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent("myJson");
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync("http://bigfont.ca", content).Result;
```

If you really want to set it for a GET, you can do this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.bigfont.ca");
message.Content = new StringContent(string.Empty);
message.Content.Headers.Clear();
message.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
var result = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that? The HttpClient API doesn't seem to allow for the setting of Content-Type as a "generic" header

Comment: Content-Type is part of a POST request not a GET. That is, a GET will not have a Content-Type header, since you are not posting any content.

Comment: I appreciate that from a HTTP standpoint, but the service uses the content-type header in a get to determine which format to send back (json, xml, or msgpack). Should it use the Accept header? Probably, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I think we both tried the same thing at the same time. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are the client and you perform a `GET` request how can you specify the `Content-Type`? Isn't it supposed to say what your are able to `Accept` ? According to this [7.2.1 Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1)  you can only set `Content-Type` when there is `Body`.

Comment: The problem is that service is not doing the right thing here. It is confusing the Accept and Content-Type (it uses Content-Type for both get and post. It is correct? No, but I still have to work with it.

Comment: Aiyyeyaa...that's not good. Are you able to share the REST service? We'd like to try :)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Shaun and I found a workaround, but thanks for your help as well.