# How to remove the default charset in HttpClient Request Header C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encoding, utf-8, httpclient

I am trying to hit an `API` from `C#` code. I am unable to get the response and receiving the status code "500 - Internal Server error".

Found the reason that the "`Charset-UTF8`" is getting appended in the request header

When i tried to hit the API in Fiddler without "`Charset-UTF8`", I am able to get the response in Fiddler and postman. With the "`Charset-UTF8`" i get the same 500 internal server error. The content type is `application/json`.

I even tried each and every charaset encoding methods  UTF-8,16,32, unicode and default format from C# code, gives the same error.

Please let me know how to remove the CharSet(appending) from the API request Header.

please go through code i have attached

```
HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
client1.BaseAddress = new Uri("i have third party url");
client1.DefaultRequestHeaders
    .Accept
    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password))));

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, client1.BaseAddress);


StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("working request"));


request.Content = content;

client1.SendAsync(request)
    .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161088/how-to-remove-charset-utf8-from-content-type-header-generated-by-httpclient-post ?

Comment: Remove cookies from you IE browser and try again.  The server is probably still using the old cookie with the UTF8 setting.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks man! I got the solution from your link. I modified few lines to get httpclient response in return.

Comment: Awesome! Can you post what you ended up with, so that future people can see the solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try the solution below

```
content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type"); // "{application/json; charset=utf-8}"
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

or

```
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
```

I have submitted an issue on `dotnet/corefx` repo.

Check it out https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25290

**Tested on** .NET Core 2.0, .NET Standard 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the client request headers outside of the request:

```
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Connection");
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Remove(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```