# C# HttpRequestMessage Content-Type force as "application/json" only

Tags: c#, api

I'm creating an HttpClient request to post an object to an API endpoint. The API endpoint only accepts "application/json" but my application changes the type to "application/json; charset=utf-8" which the API won't accept. What do I change in the StringContent to make it so it is only 'application/json'? I tried changing the encoding type from Default to null to UTF8 but that has not changed it.

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    true;
};
 var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var webRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, base_url + url)
{
    Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.Default, "application/json")
};
ebRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apitoken);
webRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
Console.WriteLine(webRequest.RequestUri);
Console.WriteLine(webRequest.Headers.ToString());
var response = client.Send(webRequest);
```

In response to the duplicates, they seem to do an Async version which is different from the version shown below. I have added more code to show the difference.

The solution was the following:[How to remove the default charset in HttpClient Request Header C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389533/how-to-remove-the-default-charset-in-httpclient-request-header-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389533/how-to-remove-the-default-charset-in-httpclient-request-header-c-sharp?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach

content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type"); // "{application/json; charset=utf-8}"
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");